# How do I fix not being able to have 2 embed commands discord bot PY

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.info'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Prices", description="T", color=246482)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.info1'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Prices", description="T", color=246482)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

This is the code I have, every time I try to make a new command ".info" doesn't work but ".info1" does. Any way to have more commands?

Comment: You can't have multiple `on_message` events, you can only have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you have two `on_message` functions when you can only have one. This means that when you define your second `on_message` function, you are overwriting your first one, which causes none of the code in the first `on_message` function to run. To fix this, you would need to put both pieces of code into one `on_message` function (which is simpler anyway!):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.info'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Prices", description="T", color=246482)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    elif message.content.startswith('.info1'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Prices", description="T", color=246482)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

However, you can see clearly that there is definitely duplication here. To fix this, just use `or` (even simpler!!!):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('.info') or message.content.startswith('.info1'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Prices", description="T", color=246482)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="e", value="e", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        embedVar.add_field(name="r", value="r", inline=False)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

However, if this is just dummy code and you need a second `elif` statement, then you can use the first example. Otherwise, either use a separate function or use the second example. (Use [the DRY coding principle!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

Also, thanks to [@Bagle's original comment on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051782/how-do-i-fix-not-being-able-to-have-2-embed-commands-discord-bot-py#comment120279445_68051782)!